# @permission_required decorator returns no user attribute in View error

Tags: django

I'm working with Django-admin panel. I have created a custom view file to add a file manager.
To make file uploading safe, I just added `permission_required` decorator. But it throws an error `'FileBrowser' object has no attribute 'user'`.

Here is my code.

```
class FileBrowser(ListView):
    model = File
    paginate_by = 30
    template_name = "file_manager/browser.html"
    extra_context = {
        'file_type': type,
        'title': "Media Browser",
    }

    @permission_required('file_manager.view_file')
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file_type = request.GET.get('type')
        self.queryset = File.objects.filter(type=file_type)
        self.extra_context['value_to'] = request.GET.get('value_to')
        self.extra_context['image_to'] = request.GET.get('image_to')
        self.extra_context['form'] = FileForm()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not decorate the method like that, since such decorator does *not* expect `self` as first parameter. It thus sees `self` as the `request` parameter.

What you can do is work with a `@method_decorator` decorator, like:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(permission_required('file_manager.view_file'), name='dispatch')
class FileBrowser(ListView):
    # …
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # …
```

For a class-based view however, you can work with the [**`PermissionRequiredMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin)

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class FileBrowser(PermissionRequiredMixin, ListView):
    permission_required = 'file_manager.view_file'
    # …

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # …
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that I'm not using @method_decorator.

Comment: @PradeepSapkota: you do not need to sue a `method_decorator` if you work with the mixin (see code fragment at the bottom). Usually using mixins is more the style of a class-based view.

Answer (score 0):

There was a small mistake in my code. But I didn't noticed that. I simply forgot to use @method_decorator and directly wrote @permission_required decorator.

This was what I wrote.

```
@permission_required('file_manager.view_file')
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    .......
    .......
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is what I changed to:

```
   @method_decorator(permission_required('file_manager.view_file'))
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       .......
       .......
       return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

Now it's working fine.
```